PurgeCss configuration using postcss plugin
According to the following commit, Angular supports PostCSS and Tailwind configuration via json config files.
Have anyone tried to use the feature for purging CSS code like Bootstrap's during build using this feature?
I am using the following config (postcss.config.json) and Angular cli gives an error at PurgeCSS.isSelectorSafelistedDeep
t.test is not a function
node_modules/purgecss/lib/purgecss.js:1:9639
{
    "plugins": {
        "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": {
            "content": [
                "src/**/*.html"
            ],
            "safelist": {
                "standard": [
                    "primary$",
                    "^mt-\\d",
                    "btn$",
                    "invalid-feedback",
                    "fade",
                    "show",
                    "collapsing",
                    "anticon$"
                ],
                "deep": [
                    "^form-\\w[a-z-]+",
                    "^modal-.*",
                    "^offcanvas-.*",
                    "^row-cols-.*",
                    "^btn-.*",
                    "^col-.*",
                    "^ant-.*",
                    "^nz-.*",
                    "^cdk-.*"
                ],
                "greedy": [],
                "keyframes": [],
                "variables": []
            },
            "skippedContentGlobs": []
        }
    }
}

It seems the expresions are not parsed correctly from json config.

Why do you need this?

I need to use purgecss to get rid of unused CSS that comes with frameworks like Bootstrap.

TailwindCSS automatically removes unused utility classes. Or let me put it this way, it only analyzes the css classes you use and creates a new css build for your project, and by analyzing it, it does not include the unused css in your project.

If you have configured your TailwindCSS correctly in Angular, you do not need to waste time on the fine tuning above. TailwindCSS does this automatically for you.
TailwindCSS statically scans and monitors your project in real time. When you use a new class, it instantly adds it to your style file or removes it from your style file if you don't use it fully. While doing this, it uses the PurgeCSS package in the background.

Tailwind may do that, but according to Angular, PostCSS can be configured using JSON and it seems this feature is not working in all cases, especially when using PostCSS plugins like PurgeCSS.
